# Unable to write to a file

Tags: java, bufferedwriter

I have gone through all the related posts in this forum and also googled but not found the exact answer.

When running the below code, I get following error:

> The constructor BufferedWriter(FileWriter) is undefined
>
> The constructor FileWriter(String) is undefined

```
public class FileWriter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        BufferedWriter f = null;

        try
        {
            f = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\A.txt"));
            f.write("Hello World");
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        finally
        {
            f.close();  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you used `import java.io.*`?

Comment: Check your imports. Are you import java.io.FileWrtier? Btw, this question has been asked before. I believe you didn't search properly.

Comment: This have error have been dicussed a hundred times already: you named your class `FileWritter` so the compiler is trying to instanciate your class instead of `java.io.FileWriter`. Rename you class.

Comment: Yes, i have used import java.io.* , still I am getting this error

Comment: I have imported java.io.* and I have also renamed the class. Still the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- I guess you want to use `java.io.FileWriter` class of java but you redefine it. You can rename your class to something else more meaningful.
- You have to import your used classes like `BufferedWriter`. That's why you get your undefined errors.
- Also it is a good practice to check if the writer `f` is `null` before closing:

---

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileWriterExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedWriter f = null;
        try {
            f = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\A.txt"));
            f.write("Hello World");
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        finally {
            if (f != null)
                f.close();  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or alternatively specify a fully-qualified type name when instantiating Java's FileWriter: `new java.io.FileWriter("C:\\A.txt")`. I like your renaming approach better though.

Answer (score 1):

Your class is called `FileWriter` which conflicts with the name of the `java.io.FileWriter`. Rename your class something else and then explicitly import the `java.io.FileWriter` and `java.io.BufferedWriter` classes.

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
```

I would also suggest using a more modern idiom: [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), which automatically closes the writer for you. It's terser and cleaner.

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\A.txt")) {
            writer.write("Hello World");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use these steps. This is the correct and easy way to use buffered writer.

1.create File object.

`File f = new File(C://A.txt);`

2. create file writer object.

`FileWriter fr = new FileWriter(f);`

3. create Buffered writer .

`BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fr);`

4.then you can easily write to the file like below.

`bw.write("Hello World");`

hope this will be help to you

remember to import

`java.io.FileWriter;`
`java.io.BufferedWriter;`
`java.io.IOException;`

those packages will be automatically suggest if you are using ide like netbeans.